# Cannot Convert From System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult To 'String' C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

C#
I am using visual studio, using windows forms, and get an error:

> Cannot Convert From System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult To 'String'

I am trying to access the Minecraft file already in my computer and want to move files to a specific folder and I let the user choose what world they want to move the mod into but when I use `System.IO.File.Move(datapack,DialogResult);` and `DialogResult` is a variable which I made here: `DialogResult DialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();` and the computer tries to convert `DialogResult` To a string for some reason and fails. so I looked up for a solution and found how to turn `DialogResult` into a string with this function `DialogResult.ToString();` but comes up with the error.

This Is My Code: (My error is on line 29 `System.IO.File.Move(datapack,DialogResult);`)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = Interaction.InputBox("You can find your username in C:/Users/Your name", "", "Put User Name In Here");
            string lastD = @"\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves";
            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\users\" + username + lastD;
            DialogResult DialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            string datapack = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mr Snout's Datapack Installer\Datapacks\Nether Reactor.zip";
            DialogResult.ToString();
            System.IO.File.Move(datapack,DialogResult);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BringToFront();
            panel1.Show();

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.SendToBack();
            panel1.Hide();
        }

        private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DialogResult doesn't return the path, but the result fx. (OK, FAILED)
Instead you use the `folderBrowserDialog1` you made, that returns the path as shown:

```
System.IO.File.Move(datapack, folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "datapack.zip");
```

Comment: That's wrong. File.Move wants a filename for the destination, not a folder.

Comment: You're right, dont know how this got marked corrent. I have edited the answer so it's right this time

Answer (score 3):

You have some confusion about what is DialogResult and what is its purpose. It is a enumeration [DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult?view=netcore-3.1) used to return the button pressed when a Dialog like FolderBrowserDialog is used. It is not the name of the folder selected by the user. This one is returned by the SelectedPath property.

So your code after getting the result from the dialog, should check if the user has pressed OK and then build the name of the destination file where you want to move your source file. This could be done extracting the file name from the source and combining it with the folder selected in the dialog.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Interaction.InputBox("You can find your username in C:/Users/Your name", "", "Put User Name In Here");
    string lastD = @"\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves";
    folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\users\" + username + lastD;
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if(result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string datapack = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mr Snout's Datapack Installer\Datapacks\Nether Reactor.zip";
        string destFile = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, Path.GetFilename(datapack));
        System.IO.File.Move(datapack,destFile);
   }
}
```